# Validate dynamically added form

Tags: jquery

I am working on a form for people to fill in and wanted to have a checkbox when if checked more forms appeared, this was not an issue but when the forms appear I want to validate them which requires a `class=""` to be set how can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Show div on check for checkbox</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      Check me <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="$(this).is(':checked') && $('#checked').slideDown('slow')|| $('#checked').slideUp('slow');" />

      <p id="checked" style="display: none; margin: 10px; height: 100px; background-color: #f5f5f5; padding: 10px" >
        <label for="form">input?</label>           
        <input  class="" type="text" name="form" id="form">
      </p>

      <script>
        $("input.checkbox").click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("input.form").addClass("required");
            Else
            $("input.form").removeClass("required");
          }
        });
      </script>    
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my code that does not seem to work, when I check the source code before and after its the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#form').addClass('required');
        } else {
            $('#form').removeClass('required');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. jQuery does not affect the source code directly, but merely the current document object model (DOM). If you still can't get it to work, try changing your

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

into

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Also, keep jQuery script tags inside the `$(document).ready(function(){});` function.

Answer (score 0):

With "more forms" I guess you´re referring to new `<input>` fields and not new `<form>`s.
Your selector `input.form` matches input elements with class "form". Is this what you want?

How and when are you extending the form? It would be better to add the "required" class at that point.

If you are looking for a way to set the class on some elements when your checkbox is checked, try something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind change event to all checkboxes
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
       // Set class "required" on all input elements
       $("input").toggleClass("required", this.checked);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I had a closer look at your code and made a better solution.

Created a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/U66VX/) where I renamed you element IDs and wrapped the input field with a `div` rather than a `p` tag.

Also concatinated your two JavaScript parts to a single event handler.

```
$('#myCheckbox').change(function() {

    var isChecked = this.checked;
    var $extendedForm = $('#extendedForm');

    if (isChecked) $extendedForm.slideDown('slow');
    else $extendedForm.slideUp('slow');

    $extendedForm.find('input').toggleClass("required", isChecked);
});
```

This JavaScript should be placed with in a `script` tag and `$(document).ready(function(){ [CODE HERE] });`